# jQuery Cycle Plugin - Skip to next slide when a condition is met

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I want know how to skip to the next slide when a certain condition is met.

Here is my code:

```
    $('#slider').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed:  200, 
        timeout: 3000,
        before: function() {
            if ($(this).attr('class') == 'empty-container') {
                $(this).cycle('next');
            }
        }
    });
```

The HTML markup for the slider is like this:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="container">......</div>
  <div class="empty-container"></div>
  <div class="container">......</div>
</div>
```

When div with "empty-container" class is encountered, I'd like to immediately skip to the next slide. I know the easiest way to achieve this is by using `slideExpr` option but due to multiple pager markups in the same slideshow, I am unable to use `slideExpr`.

Comment: why not remove the empty container(s) before initializing cycle? Also what does `multiple pager markups` mean. If removing is not an option, provide markup

Comment: @charlietfl It's due to some elements in the pager that still need to map to the empty containers. So the empty containers should remain there but I just need to figure out a way to skip them.

Comment: @charlietfl "multiple pagers" are the navigation buttons on top and bottom of the slideshow.

Comment: you need to check next slide , not `this` in `before` callback. Use arguments shown in options in cycle docs. Pagers can also be dynamically generated within plugin , so still not sure why empties can't be removed...  let plugin create pager and issue dissapears

Comment: @charlietfl The plugin can create pagers only on one side but not on 2 different sides of the slideshow with auto slide. My markup is something like this: `<div class="top-pager">...</div><div id="slider">...</div><div class="bottom-pager">...</div>`. Sorry I didn't quite understand what you meant by `check next slide`. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `before:` option, I used `after:` and it now seems to work fine for my particular problem. So the jquery is now:

```
$('#slider').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed:  200, 
        timeout: 3000,
        after: function() {
            if ($(this).attr('class') == 'empty-container') {
                $(this).cycle('next');
            }
        }
    });
```